# Mongodb restore some collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, backup, restore

I have a mongoDB remote and I want to restore only some collections to the remote mongodb. Any suggestions how to do that.

```
mongorestore -d DBNAME -c categories DBNAMENEW/heroku_mb4p0d3s/categories.bson
```

The above command works because it is in local. But same command doesnt work for remote

```
'mongorestore -d DBNAME -c categories -o --host host.mlab.com --port 1111 --username username --password password -d databasename/categories.bson'
```

Any idea where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mongorestore --db DBNAME --collection categories  --host host.mlab.com --port 1111 --username username --password password categories.bson
```

It will restore specific .bson to that collection

Answer (score 0):

Restore a Collection use the following example :

mongorestore --db accounts --collection people  --host 192.168.1.116:27018  --port 27017 /opt/backup/mongodumpfile

read about mongorestore https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/